# Database of readings for Japanese words

Tags: sorting, nlp

Does anyone know of an off-the-shelf database that provides phonetic (kana) readings for Japanese words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming what you *actually* mean is you want a computer readable offline Japanese dictionary then look at [JMDict](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/edict_doc.html)  (or the older edict) are Japanese dictionaries which have reading entries (in Kanji/Kana) with an associated kana reading element. The JMDict is in XML so it is pretty simple to use with most projects.

Answer (score 0):

http://kakasi.namazu.org/index.html.ja is another option, however be aware that whatever solution you choose, the mapping isn't 1 to 1.  Without sufficient context, there will be many cases where the proper reading is ambiguous.

Comment: Also, there is a very simple Google API you can use for this as well, if you don't mind requiring network access and depending on them not changing the API.

Answer (score -1):

One project that comes to mind is [Gozoku](http://int64.org/projects/gozoku), which comes with a English<->Japanese SQLite database, as well as kana readings for Japanese words. I haven't taken a look at the schema, but you might find what you're looking for in there.